# How to integrate a containerized web component (React) via Docker?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, web

I've been trying to integrate a "React" web component for a few days.

Our web component is now hosted in a "Docker" image and exposed on an URL.
This URL therefore does not correspond to the file (.js) of the app, but the complete DOM of the app hosted by nginx web server .
We would like to be able to allow different partners to be able to integrate this component easily on a web page.

Unfortunately we cannot find any documentation on this subject.

We would like to avoid the use of an (`<iframe>`) for various user experiences and slow loading concerns.

**Would it be a solution to mount a docker image that would just act as a web file server to simply expose the app's .js file?**

What's the best practices ?

Thank you in advance

**Here is our Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:14.15.4-alpine3.12 as builder
WORKDIR /app

RUN npm config set registry https://private-repo-url/npm/npm/
RUN npm config set strict-ssl false

COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:stable-alpine

RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./config/env.sh .
COPY ./config/.env.*.js ./

# Add bash
RUN apk add --no-cache bash

# Make our shell script executable
RUN chmod +x env.sh

# Start Nginx server
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/usr/share/nginx/html/env.sh && nginx -g \"daemon off;\""]
```

Answer (score 0):

The build I do separately in github workflow, this is how I do it:

```
FROM nginx:1.19.0
EXPOSE 80
COPY ./config/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY build/ /usr/share/nginx/html/admin
```

and `./config/nginx/nginx.conf` is this:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.html =404;
  }
}
```